Neo4J Cypher Not Using Index
I am trying to insert a number of rows (more than 1 mil) from a CSV file into the graph database, the treasure table needs a relationship to a city, as in a treasure is found in ever city. city_id is formatted as such: 0x6234F00E0E994A6D8A7C5040FCA8CC1B.
I have created an index yet neo4j doesn't seem to be using it:
// Create index to speed up insertion
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS FOR (ci:City) ON (ci.id);

// Load treasures and link to cities
:auto LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///treasure.csv' AS row_treasure
CALL {
    WITH row_treasure
    CREATE (t:Treasure {id: row_treasure[0], difficulty: toInteger(row_treasure[1]), terrain: toInteger(row_treasure[2]), city_id: row_treasure[3]})
    WITH t, row_treasure
    MATCH (ci:City {id: row_treasure[3]})
    CREATE (t)-[:HIDDEN_IN]->(ci)
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 500 ROWS;


This index not being used leads to greater than 10 minute wait time for 500 entries to be inserted. Elsewhere in the same execution I am also using an index yet this one is used correctly:
// Create index to speed up insertion
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS FOR (co:Country) ON (co.code);

// Load cities and link to countries
:auto LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///city.csv' AS row_city
CALL {
    WITH row_city
CREATE (ci:City {id: row_city[0], city_name: row_city[1], latitude: row_city[2], longitude: row_city[3], postal_code: row_city[4], country_code: row_city[5]})
WITH ci, row_city
MATCH (co:Country {code: row_city[5]})
CREATE (ci)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(co)
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 500 ROWS;


I have tried looking up different types of indexes and how to use them but I have generally been unable to find a solution that does work and uses the indexes.

Are you sure that treasure.csv and city.csv are using the same city id values? Also, ideally your second query should create the City index (CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS FOR (ci:City) ON (ci.id);), since it is creating City nodes.

Yeah they are definitely using the same id values, both queries are executed at the same time one after the other, the second one is further up in the same execution plan. After looking further yesterday it does seem like the index is being used but it is still incredibly slow, I guess because city has a million or so rows and every time a treasure is inserted it has to loop through them all. I have no idea how to speed it up

If you create an index after creating a lot of nodes that belong in the index, it will take time. And if you try to use the index while it is still adding nodes, it should not be surprising if it is slow. So you should create the index before you create relevant nodes, not right before you need to use the index. That gives you the best chance that the index has finished updating by the time you need it.

Also, the time to lookup up a city using its index should be independent of how many relationships it has.

I worked out how to optimize the inserts, it was a combination of moving the creation of indexes to earlier and using foreach, match and compress, thanks

Not sure if this is required or would make a difference, but to speed up the match you might try "USING INDEX SEEK n:LABEL(Property)" to force using index. My guess is creating indexed nodes as you go is slowing down the process.
